# apprequest for a website

Tags: facebook, web, fb.ui

I m workin a projet and the marketing dep have the clever idea to a "invite friend" (apprequest) dialog on the website (with facebook connect)

I would if it is possible , as I read that on the facebook online docs

```
Requests are only available for Desktop Canvas apps and not website
```

However, the dialog displays anyway , but no notification are sent.

Comment: did anyone find a solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

You'd have to have a canvas implementation in order for the requests to be displayed and for users to be able to accept them.

If you can't do this, maybe look at using the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) for an alternative way to get a user to post a link to your app

Others may suggest setting up a canvas URL solely to redirect back to the website but be aware that that's against [Facebook policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) I.12

Comment: It s not an app, it s an external website ,  what did you mean by "canvas implementation" , the request are successfully displayed but not sent.

Comment: If it's a canvas app, the requests are displayed and it will bring users to the canvas (apps.facebook.com/whatever) when they accept them.